# Reclaiming Company's Apple Developer Account

Tags: ios, app-store

I joined a company last year, and have been managing their Android app.

We also have plans to launch an iOS app, for which we have been trying to reclaim access to the company's developer ID for the past year.

The context is, that this company's previous team left around 2 years ago, including the tech people. Last year when we tried creating an Apple Developer ID with the legal paperwork (DUNS number etc), Apple support informed us that a team already exists for the company.

They are not telling us the details of the owner of this team/ID. All they have done so far is tell us to ask this person to add our IDs to the team, and when we told them that we have no idea who this person could be, inform us that they have told this person to contact us. We haven't heard from anyone for a year on this, and neither is Apple support being actually helpful.

Since the Apple Developer ID is linked to the legal status of the company, we (part of the new management) should have a channel to be able to reclaim the ID, so that we can develop and release our app.

Has anyone here faced a similar issue? Any pointers on where to start to solve the problem?

Comment: Who is paying the bill? Apple wouldn't keep your program in good standing if someone wasn't renewing the membership?  You will need to persist with Apple developer support.  You should be able to provide them with legal documentation or a letter under your company seal that requests a change of program owner. Probably work with your company legal team.

Comment: Thank you Paulw11 for the inputs. I managed to speak to someone at Apple Developer support over a phone call, and insisted on reclaiming the account while promising to fulfill whatever legal steps they required for it. It took around a week, and we were able to recover the account.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I was successful in getting the account back.

All it took was to get to talk to a human. I scheduled a callback on the Apple Developer support page, and spoke to the developer support team and explained the entire situation to them. They understood my problem and promised a resolution. It took around a week, and involved sharing paperwork about the company and the representative from the company who would be the new Account Holder.

Once the documents were shared, they took another 3-4 days and made our rep the AH.

Hope that helps anyone else facing the same issue.